# Oscillating solutions to Friedmann equations

Tags: cosmology, universe, oscillators

Does homogeneous and isotropic Friedmann cosmologies allow for periodic (simple harmonic solutions) Universes? Can they (universal oscillators) solve the issue of the initial (or future) singularities?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_model Maybe you can also find some information in textbooks.

Answer (score 0):

The values of the four Omega variables of the Friedmann equation determines the pattern of how the dynamics of the universe behaves. Based on the currently determined values for the Omega variables, the universe will only expand, and the rate of expansion will decrease towards a constant value for the Hubble constant H(t). Note that in the chart referenced below

https://map.gsfc.nasa.gov/media/990350/990350b.jpg

only one curve has Omegas summed to unity, which is a requirement for an accurate model
.